# How did we get $ p\sum_{n=1}^{∞} (1-p)^{n-1}=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions

I am not sure how we got below expression..
$$\sum_{n=1}^{∞} P(X=n)= p\sum_{n=1}^{∞} (1-p)^{n-1} = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)} = 1$$

I understand that we calculate expected value for n trials using linearity of expectations. I just do not understand algebraic part : 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{∞} (1-p)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-(1-p)}$$

Can someone explain this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If -1 < p <1, then you can use the infinite geometric series equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

$\sum_{n=1}^{∞} (1-p)^{n-1} = 1+ (1-p) + (1-p)^2 + (1-p)^3+... = \frac{1}{1-(1-p)} $

Answer (score 4):

Sum of [Infinite geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series)
$a,ar,ar^2\cdots$

$|r|\lt1$
is given as

$$s=\frac{a}{1-r}$$

Hence
for $|x|\lt1$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 3):

Sum the geometric series. It may help to rewrite it as $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-p)^n.$$
$$
p\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p)^{n-1}=p\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-p)^n=p\left(1\over 1-(1-p)\right)=p\cdot {1\over p}=1,
$$
which is valid for $|1-p|<1$.